# macOS files "connected" but no symlink?

Tags: macos, copy-paste, file, symlink

###### Disclaimer

I’m not sure how to even phrase the issue here. So if you find a better way, please comment it, I’ll edit the question.

I don’t know either if it’s a LyX or macOS related question. So please, point me towards the right direction.

##### The question

On a macOS computer, I was editing `newfile.lyx` in `folder1/`. Then, to organize, I moved (drag and drop) the LyX file along with the bib file attached to it to `folder1/folder2/`.

First, it apparently didn’t just **move** the file, but rather **copied and paste** to `folder2/`, because I still have the `newfile.lyx` in `folder1/` as well as having it in `folder2/`.

Second, and most importantly, the two files are “*connected*”. By that I mean that when I modify either file (they both have the same name, just not the same path) the other gets updated with the modification made to the other file, and vice versa.

I verified if for some reason it there was a symbolic link linking the two files, but there is no link at all.

Any idea why that could be?

#### Edit

the output of `ls -li@ newfile.lyx* folder1/newfile.lyx*`:

```
46648505 -rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  50670  4 avr 18:17 Note de synthèse.lyx
46599280 -rw-r--r--@ 1 user  staff  46456  3 avr 18:16 Note de synthèse.lyx~
    com.apple.lastuseddate#PS      16 
46553281 -rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  41032  2 avr 23:31 Notedesynthèse/Note de synthèse.lyx
45829824 -rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  14231 30 mar 11:12 Notedesynthèse/Note de synthèse.lyx.emergency
46540826 -rw-r--r--@ 1 user  staff  40983  2 avr 23:22 Notedesynthèse/Note de synthèse.lyx~
    com.apple.lastuseddate#PS      16
```

Comment: Are you seeing this in LyX only or also in Finder?

Comment: In finder as well.

Comment: There could be 2 hard links to the file. However in your case, it would appear you created an alias. In other words, you held down the command-option keys while dragging and dropping the file.

Comment: can you open Terminal, `cd` into folder 1, run `ls -l newfile.lyx folder2/newfile.lyx` and copy/paste the output into the question as text?

Comment: @DavidAnderson Sorry for late reply… What’s an alias?

Comment: @nohillside done.

Comment: The information you added doesn’t support the „the files are connected“ hypothesis: They have the same name but file size as well as timestamp are different. They also have different inodes.

Comment: Maybe Lyx got confused and you kept editing the files in folder1 instead of the new ones in folder2? At least that‘s what the timestamp implies.

Comment: Louis: You are not using an alias. However since you asked, the [macOS Users Guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-and-remove-aliases-on-mac-mchlp1046/13.0/mac/13.0) defines a alias as the following. *"A shortcut to an app, file, or folder that you can keep anywhere on your Mac. When you create an alias for an item, the original item doesn’t move. When you open an alias, the original item opens. If you move or rename the original item, the link between it and the alias remains."*

Comment: @nohillside You’re right. The hypothesis doesn’t hold up to this information. Even more so, when editing the `.lyx` file in vim, the other doesn’t get the edit. However, when editing with LyX any of the two files, the other gets updated with the edit and vice versa. So, it must be something with LyX rather than system wise. Anyways, thanks for your help.